# How to disable autocomplete for passwords in IE8 via GPO?

Tags: windows, group-policy, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8

In IE6 there was a registry key hidden away that would allow you to enable autocomplete but only for usernames, not passwords.

This key no longer has any effect in IE8. I can either enable or disable autocomplete for usernames and passwords, but not just one of the two.

What I'm looking for is a way to enable autocomplete for usernames, but disable it for passwords.

Is there a way to do this in IE8?

Comment: I'll definitely be interested to hear this. If I had time this morning to look into it I would. I detest password autocomplete in corporate environments.

Comment: Thanks for this question, I just made the change to my GPO as well. Hadn't even thought of this.

Answer (score 2):

I believe there is a GPO template available from Microsoft for this.  Here is a listing of all the GPO settings available for IE8, they do list some entries for disabling Autocomplete under Windows Components\Internet Explorer\Internet Settings\AutoComplete

I can't see any settings listed for just passwords though

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc985351.aspx

Comment: There is a GPO setting to "Turn off autocomplete for usernames and passwords" but there is no equivalent for just passwords.