# Microsoft Office 2007 system missing from GPedit

Tags: windows-7, group-policy

I'm trying to change some security settings in Group Policy for Windows 7 x64 to comply with [DISA STIG viewer](http://iase.disa.mil/stigs/); its flagging a lot of presets for the 2007 Microsoft Office Suite.  When I attempt to navigate to the correct subfolder (Microsoft Office 2007 system (Machine)) in gpedit.msc, the location is mysteriously missing.

Example:
[Disable user name and password](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc148228.aspx)

I launch gpedit.msc, Navigate to Local Computer Policy -> Computer Configuration -> Administrative templates -> the folder "Microsoft Office 2007 system (Machine)" is not listed.  I've checked the filter options and set them to "any" as well as disabling the filter.  I tried to perform a Windows search for "powerpnt" and "pptview", which STIG said were related to the setting I was supposed to change and both searches returned 0 results.

**Note**: I'm still able to launch Powerpoint and the other applications just fine, so it doesn't appear to be a bad install.

I've already read threads: [one](https://serverfault.com/questions/109696/group-policy-trusted-location-in-users-my-documents), [two](https://serverfault.com/questions/290620/battling-with-office-2007-2010-gpos) and [three](https://serverfault.com/questions/27981/how-to-disable-autocomplete-for-passwords-in-ie8-via-gpo) and none of them seem related to the problem that I'm having.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You first have to [add](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/932493) the [Microsoft Office 2007 group policy templates](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=22666) in order to be able to configure Microsoft Office 2007 settings in Group Policy.

After downloading Admin Templates.exe, the file should be about 9.5MB large, if it's smaller and you recieve an error message saying that Admin Templates.exe is not a valid Win32 Application, re-download the program.

Comment: This is the correct answer. The admin templates can be found here http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=22666

Comment: @joeqwerty Thanks for the qucik response.  I'm downloading a copy from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?displaylang=en&id=22666), but I'm an _extremely_ slow connection, so it'll e an hour or so before I can test it out.  I will respond with results.

Comment: Glad to help...

Comment: @joeqwerty could you mention in your response on how to add a group policy template in your answer, so if anyone else has this or a similar problem, they know what to do after they download the template?

Comment: Well, how to do it will depend on the domain. If it's a W2K3 domain you'll add the templates (ADM files) to the GPO itself. If it's a W2K8 domain you'll add the templates (ADMX files and language files) to the GPO central store, assuming that you've created the GPO central store (and why wouldn't you?).

Comment: @joeqwerty I managed to download AdminTemplates, but when I tried to run it, I got the following error: "D:\(PATH)\AdminTemplates.exe is not a valid Win32 application." I tried to run in compatibility mode but have not had any luck.  I'm trying to re-download now to ensure it wasn't just a "bad copy" or whatever.